# Display multi-dimensional database documents in a Meteor web app

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I've decided to use Meteor for my current web application project. On this website, we want the user to have their own inventory of cars and need to display them from a Mongo Collection in the following format using Meteor's Sidebars templating engine.

```
Car 1
    Engine: 6-cylinder
    Color: black
Car 2
    Engine: 4-cylinder
    Color: white
```

Our templates are setup as follows:

```
<template name=”cars”>
    {{#each cars}}
        {{> car}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name=”car”>
    Engine: {{engine}}
    Color: {{color}}
</template>
```

Our helpers:

```
Template.cars.helpers({
    return Cars.find({ownerId: Meteor.user_id()});
});

Template.car.helpers({
    engine: function(){
        var car_id = “???”;
        return Car.findOne({car_id: car_id}).engine;
     },

    color: function(){
        var car_id = “???”;
        return Car.findOne({car_id: car_id}).color;

    },
});
```

My issue is passing the car_id to the helper functions. I know that we can pass an argument to the helper function through the data attribute on the template like `{{car data=carId}}` but then we would need to pass the car_id from `Template.cars.helpers`.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing or am I misunderstanding the fundamentals of Meteor and Sidebars?

Note: The actual application has nothing to do with cars and is not this simple. Due to this, it is necessary to have separate Mongo Collections to hold Cars and Car attributes.

Comment: I don't know what the collections look like and what the relationship between `Cars` and `Car` is, but you can access the properties of the `Cars` document inside the helpers as `this`. So you probably want `this._id` or `this.car_id`.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a cursor with `#each`, the inner context becomes a single document. In your example, the `car` template has the context of a car document. Because of this, no helpers are necessary in order to render `{{engine}}` or `{{color}}`.

To better understand this, I'd recommend reading [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/).

If, however, you need the `_id` of the car inside of a helper in order to perform some other action (a collection join perhaps), then you can access  it via `this._id` (again the context of a helper in this example is a document). Here's an example:

```js
Template.car.helpers({
  driver: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({carId: this._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! "this" was the missing ingredient. And to think I spent 5 hours trying to figure this out :-/

Answer (score 1):

The way you have set it up you are doing a search first in cars, and then for each record in cars you are doing a findOne for a car in the car table, right? This is probably causing not one, but two problems.

Firstly you have the problem of passing the car_id which you have mentioned, and secondly you have a problem of speed, because looking up in the individual car table one by one for each record that you found in the cars table takes time.

If you really must keep these two separate tables, then I would suggest that you do all the database work in the first helper, and eliminate the second helper.

In other words, in the first helper look up all the records in the cars table, then in the same helper look up all the records in the individual car table and pass this new array to #each cars. That way you can eliminate the template.car.helper and leave Blaze to deal with it in the normal Meteor way.